# How to get IE11, IE10, and IE9 to run their respective versions

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, ie-compatibility-mode

I have a website where a lot of users might have compatibility mode engaged, and that's causing me all sorts of problems with `Angular` and other various things. I can fix it if I can somehow get `IE 9`, `IE 10`, and `IE 11` to run their versions. I don't want to use Edge as this is a production site, I want to keep control over things as much as possible. Which is the way to go here?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11,IE=10,IE=9" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,IE=10,IE=11" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MSDN documentation,

> The values of the *content* attribute are read *left to right*; Internet
>   Explorer uses the highest supported value. If a webpage specifies a
>   document compatibility mode that isn't supported by the version of
>   Internet Explorer used to view the webpage, the webpage uses the
>   highest version of standard mode supported by the browser

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

But please take note that IE supports more than one requested document mode. You have to make an guess-timate (if stats are not available) of what versions of IE your users have out there and make that your basis of what document compatibilities to use